# Нейросеть, как средство сжатия для поиска информации в больших объемах. Возможно ли?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Есть задача. Нужно сохранить 6 байтные числа, разбив их на 100 файлов по 2,5 млрд. чисел в каждом. В дальнейшем будет даваться число, нужно определить, к какому файлу оно относится.
Если сохранять "в лоб", то выходит 6 байт * 2,5 млрд = 14 ГБ на файл. Всего 1,4 ТБ.
Пришел к решению: 3 байта - индекс, 3 - данные. Объем каждого файла сократился почти в 2 раза. Поиск очень быстрый. Нашел способ сжатия блоков данных - получил 6 ГБ на файл. 100 файлов - необходимый минимум, а это уже 600 ГБ.

А что, если применить нейросети? Знаком с ними плохо. Понимаю, что сети работают на закономерностях, обучаются на одних данных, работают с другими. У меня же данные случайны и учить придется все.
Подавать на вход 48 бит, на выходе получать число 1 - 100.

1) Будет ли это (поиск) вообще работать?

2) Если да, то даст ли сокращение объема хранения?

3) Сколько времени займет обучение? Думаю, самое узкое место.

Comment: Задача в том чтобы определить какому из 100 файлов принадлежит число или в том чтобы сохранить число в одном из файлов? Нейросеть никак не поможет уменьшить объём хранения чисел...

Comment: @MaxU, именно определить к какому числу (из 100) оно относится

Comment: Можете подробней описать задачу? По какому критерию разбиваются числа? Вы не рассматривали возможность использования "хеш-партиционирования"?

Comment: @MaxU, Даны числа 1 - 100. Каждому из них соответствует некоторое множество 6-байтных чисел от 0x000000000000 до 0xffffffffffff. Задача, имея произвольное 6-байтное, определить соответствующее ему число от 1 до 100

Comment: Вот этот момент я и просил уточнить: `Каждому из них соответствует некоторое множество 6-байтных чисел от 0x000000000000 до 0xffffffffffff.`

Comment: банальная идея: используйте остаток от деления числа на 100 в качестве номера файла и для записи и для чтения

Comment: @MaxU, Вы не поняли. Числу 100 может соответствовать любое, хоть 10500. хоть 11256... Деление тут ничего не даст. Да уже понял, что уменьшить размер врядли получится. Если только усовершенствовать алгоритм сжатия. Лучше приобрести диск на 3-4 ТБ и все влезет